# Java use a class object as a return type in another class

Tags: java, class, return, call, return-type

I have a question with about Java classes. I have two classes, and I want to use one of them as a return type in another one. How can I do it?

The one that I want to use as a return type simply is:

```
public class Pair<F, S> {
  private F first; 
  private S second; 

  public Pair(F first, S second) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
  }
```

I want a method from another class to use this as below.

```
public static Pair<Array<Pair<Entity, int>>, int> myMethod(String x, int delta);
```

Then I should have a return as:

```
([(Entity("table"), 2)], 2)
```

Comment: "`Pair<Array<Pair<Entity, int>>, int>`" is not a type you should ever want to be using. You probably mean `Integer`, not `int`; but this type is just foul. Define specific class(es) to represent the parts of this type in semantically-meaningful ways.

Comment: I have a specific class called Pair which returns a pair like (x,y). x and y could be string or integer. I need to use this pair object as a return type in another class

Comment: No, `Pair` isn't a specific class. What do the `String` and the `Integer` mean? Name and Age? First school and number of dogs owned? Define a type with fields which convey their *meaning*, not just the *type*.